# How to get Native Splash Screen in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, native, splash-screen

Is there any way to remove default native Splash screen in Flutter. I want to show my own splash screen instead of default black screen.

Comment: see [Adding a splash screen to your mobile app](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/advanced/splash-screen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Splash screen can't be provided through Flutter as iOS and Android both have a different way to show.

**`iOS:`** The default Flutter template includes an Xcode storyboard named ***LaunchScreen.storyboard*** that can be used to show your splash screen.

**`Android:`** The default Flutter project template includes a definition of a launch theme and a launched background. You can customize this by editing **styles.xml**, where you can define a theme whose ***windowBackground*** is set to the Drawable that should be displayed as the launch screen.

> Source: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/advanced/splash-screen